# How do I use embedded Auth0 Lock in a NextJS app?

Tags: authentication, next.js, auth0, server-side-rendering

I am working on a NextJS app where one developer implemented [@auth0/nextjs-auth0](https://github.com/auth0/nextjs-auth0). We want to EMBED the Lock form within a custom login page (not the redirect method, but the [embed method](https://auth0.com/docs/guides/login/universal-vs-embedded)). What are the options for making this happen?